# Fluentd Elasticsearch Kibana logs dynamic index GEOPOINT mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, geopoints

I am using EFK logging stack and have managed to set up fluentd filter and match configurations so that the tomcat access logs collected in Kibana all needed fields are there: IP, latitude, longitude, City, country code, etc.

I have `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @fluentd_mapping.json http://$host/fluentd/fluentd/_mapping` but it only affects the fluentd index. Not the dynamically created daily-log index `<foo>.access.logs.*`

So my question is how to apply the mapping so that the geo_point type is effective for the daily log index? Thanks.

I restarted the ES container, `curl -XPUT` the following mapping.json which is picked up by fluentd index but not the daily-log index:

```
{
    "fluentd": {
        "location_array": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "location_properties": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "location_string": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
    }
}
```

Existing templates:

```
                "dynamic_templates": [{
    "kibana_index_template:.kibana": {
                "dynamic_templates": [{
    "security-index-template": {
                "dynamic_templates": [{
                        "path_match": "result\\.(input(\\..+)*|(transform(\\..+)*)|(actions\\.transform(\\..+)*))\\.search\\.request\\.(body|template)",
    "logstash-index-template": {
```

Existing index patterns:

```
        "index_patterns": [".monitoring-logstash-6-*"],
        "index_patterns": [".monitoring-kibana-6-*"],
        "index_patterns": [".ml-anomalies-*"],
        "index_patterns": [".kibana"],
        "index_patterns": [".ml-state"],
        "index_patterns": [".watches*"],
        "index_patterns": [".monitoring-beats-6-*"],
        "index_patterns": [".monitoring-es-6-*"],
        "index_patterns": [".security_audit_log*"],
        "index_patterns": [".ml-meta"],
        "index_patterns": [".security-*"],
        "index_patterns": [".triggered_watches*"],
        "index_patterns": [".watcher-history-9*"],
        "index_patterns": [".monitoring-alerts-6"],
        "index_patterns": [".ml-notifications"],
        "index_patterns": [".logstash"],
```

I added the following template but to no avail:

```
        "fluentd": {
                "order": 0,
                "index_patterns": ["myapp.access.logs*"],
                "settings": {},
                "mappings": {
                        "fluentd": {
                                "properties": {
                                        "location_array": {
                                                "type": "geo_point"
                                        },
                                        "location_properties": {
                                                "type": "geo_point"
                                        },
                                        "location_string": {
                                                "type": "geo_point"
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "aliases": {}
        },
```

It's not picked up by myapp.access.logs-

Comment: In the template you added, just change "fluentd" to "_doc" and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify the content of fluentd_mapping.json for clarity, but it looks like the indices have different name pattern and that is the reason the mapping is not applied to all the indices.

you should use elasticsearch template in order to configure the geoip mapping. in the template take a look at "index_patterns" which describe the indices matching condition. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

once the index_patterns regex will match all the indices you need (including the access logs index) then the GEOIP mapping and all the rest will get applied as expected.

Comment: My fluentd mapping is not of concern as I see that in fluentd index. The dynamically/automatically created daily-log index uses that mapping but strange engouh the geo_point appears in fluentd index but not the daily-log index mapping.

Comment: How do I change the index_patterns? It seems global.

Comment: do you use index template for those daily indices? can you paste the template and the index mapping? I think that you don't have the right mapping for the daily indices, and that's why the geo_point is not detected

Comment: note that you can't change the mapping in an existing index (in case a mapping already exist for the requested field), so you have to: 1. set up the right template, 2. create a new index, with a pattern that will match the template.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with index template for those daily indices. I restart the ES container, `curl -XPUT` the mapping.json and see that picked up by fluentd but not the daily-log indices.

Comment: You need to read the docs, in the link I pasted above, about what is Elasticsearch Index Template: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html . A template is a placeholder for settings of future indices that will get created in the cluster. Indices that are created are matched against the index_patterns of the existing templates. then all the matched templates are being merged based on the 'order' and that contains the initial mapping of the index. you need to set up the geo_point mapping IN THE TEMPLATE in order for future daily indices to have it.

Comment: `curl localhost:9200/_template` shows the existing template included in my updated post. Should I update one of the existing template or create new?

Comment: the template is cut. you need to look for the template with the geo_point mapping, and check its 'index_patterns' to see that it would match the daily indices. you can update the existing template

Comment: The curl output is a result of `grep` for template. There is no geo_point mapping at all. How to update the existing template? Which template to update? without damaging the existing ones?

Comment: what is the type of logs you are sending? which es version? the template you added looks good, but only for log type 'fluentd', maybe this is a different type?

Comment: fluentd, as mentioned clearly in the subject topic. ES 6.5.4.

Comment: in ES 6.5 you have to use _doc as the type, not fluentd. the real ES type is '_type', which is different from 'type' field inside the doc.

Comment: see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html